# Multisignature contract process got the error TypeError: Cannot access member 'call' of undefined

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, multisignature

First step i start the geth like this

```
geth --testnet --natspec --rpc --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpcport 8545 --rpcapi "personal,eth,web3,net"
```

Then I run the following code:

```
//Multisignature source code for compiling

primaryAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
 var testSource=' contract multiowned { struct PendingState { uint yetNeeded; uint ownersDone; uint index; } event Confirmation(address owner, bytes32 operation); event Revoke(address owner, bytes32 operation); event OwnerChanged(address oldOwner, address newOwner); event OwnerAdded(address newOwner); event OwnerRemoved(address oldOwner); event RequirementChanged(uint newRequirement); modifier onlyowner { if (isOwner(msg.sender)) _ } modifier onlymanyowners(bytes32 _operation) { if (confirmAndCheck(_operation)) _ } function multiowned(address[] _owners, uint _required) { m_numOwners = _owners.length + 1; m_owners[1] = uint(msg.sender); m_ownerIndex[uint(msg.sender)] = 1; for (uint i = 0; i < _owners.length; ++i) { m_owners[2 + i] = uint(_owners[i]); m_ownerIndex[uint(_owners[i])] = 2 + i; } m_required = _required; } function revoke(bytes32 _operation) external { uint ownerIndex = m_ownerIndex[uint(msg.sender)]; if (ownerIndex == 0) return; uint ownerIndexBit = 2**ownerIndex; var pending = m_pending[_operation]; if (pending.ownersDone & ownerIndexBit > 0) { pending.yetNeeded++; pending.ownersDone -= ownerIndexBit; Revoke(msg.sender, _operation); } } function changeOwner(address _from, address _to) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external { if (isOwner(_to)) return; uint ownerIndex = m_ownerIndex[uint(_from)]; if (ownerIndex == 0) return; clearPending(); m_owners[ownerIndex] = uint(_to); m_ownerIndex[uint(_from)] = 0; m_ownerIndex[uint(_to)] = ownerIndex; OwnerChanged(_from, _to); } function addOwner(address _owner) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external { if (isOwner(_owner)) return; clearPending(); if (m_numOwners >= c_maxOwners) reorganizeOwners(); if (m_numOwners >= c_maxOwners) return; m_numOwners++; m_owners[m_numOwners] = uint(_owner); m_ownerIndex[uint(_owner)] = m_numOwners; OwnerAdded(_owner); } function removeOwner(address _owner) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external { uint ownerIndex = m_ownerIndex[uint(_owner)]; if (ownerIndex == 0) return; if (m_required > m_numOwners - 1) return; m_owners[ownerIndex] = 0; m_ownerIndex[uint(_owner)] = 0; clearPending(); reorganizeOwners(); OwnerRemoved(_owner); } function changeRequirement(uint _newRequired) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external { if (_newRequired > m_numOwners) return; m_required = _newRequired; clearPending(); RequirementChanged(_newRequired); } function isOwner(address _addr) returns (bool) { return m_ownerIndex[uint(_addr)] > 0; } function hasConfirmed(bytes32 _operation, address _owner) constant returns (bool) { var pending = m_pending[_operation]; uint ownerIndex = m_ownerIndex[uint(_owner)]; if (ownerIndex == 0) return false; uint ownerIndexBit = 2**ownerIndex; if (pending.ownersDone & ownerIndexBit == 0) { return false; } else { return true; } } function confirmAndCheck(bytes32 _operation) internal returns (bool) { uint ownerIndex = m_ownerIndex[uint(msg.sender)]; if (ownerIndex == 0) return; var pending = m_pending[_operation]; if (pending.yetNeeded == 0) { pending.yetNeeded = m_required; pending.ownersDone = 0; pending.index = m_pendingIndex.length++; m_pendingIndex[pending.index] = _operation; } uint ownerIndexBit = 2**ownerIndex; if (pending.ownersDone & ownerIndexBit == 0) { Confirmation(msg.sender, _operation); if (pending.yetNeeded <= 1) { delete m_pendingIndex[m_pending[_operation].index]; delete m_pending[_operation]; return true; } else { pending.yetNeeded--; pending.ownersDone |= ownerIndexBit; } } } function reorganizeOwners() private returns (bool) { uint free = 1; while (free < m_numOwners) { while (free < m_numOwners && m_owners[free] != 0) free++; while (m_numOwners > 1 && m_owners[m_numOwners] == 0) m_numOwners--; if (free < m_numOwners && m_owners[m_numOwners] != 0 && m_owners[free] == 0) { m_owners[free] = m_owners[m_numOwners]; m_ownerIndex[m_owners[free]] = free; m_owners[m_numOwners] = 0; } } } function clearPending() internal { uint length = m_pendingIndex.length; for (uint i = 0; i < length; ++i) if (m_pendingIndex[i] != 0) delete m_pending[m_pendingIndex[i]]; delete m_pendingIndex; } uint public m_required; uint public m_numOwners; uint[256] m_owners; uint constant c_maxOwners = 250; mapping(uint => uint) m_ownerIndex; mapping(bytes32 => PendingState) m_pending; bytes32[] m_pendingIndex; } contract daylimit is multiowned { modifier limitedDaily(uint _value) { if (underLimit(_value)) _ } function daylimit(uint _limit) { m_dailyLimit = _limit; m_lastDay = today(); } function setDailyLimit(uint _newLimit) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external { m_dailyLimit = _newLimit; } function resetSpentToday() onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external { m_spentToday = 0; } function underLimit(uint _value) internal onlyowner returns (bool) { if (today() > m_lastDay) { m_spentToday = 0; m_lastDay = today(); } if (m_spentToday + _value >= m_spentToday && m_spentToday + _value <= m_dailyLimit) { m_spentToday += _value; return true; } return false; } function today() private constant returns (uint) { return now / 1 days; } uint public m_dailyLimit; uint public m_spentToday; uint public m_lastDay; } contract multisig { event Deposit(address from, uint value); event SingleTransact(address owner, uint value, address to, bytes data); event MultiTransact(address owner, bytes32 operation, uint value, address to, bytes data); event ConfirmationNeeded(bytes32 operation, address initiator, uint value, address to, bytes data); function changeOwner(address _from, address _to) external; function execute(address _to, uint _value, bytes _data) external returns (bytes32); function confirm(bytes32 _h) returns (bool); } contract Wallet is multisig, multiowned, daylimit { uint public version = 2; struct Transaction { address to; uint value; bytes data; } function Wallet(address[] _owners, uint _required, uint _daylimit) multiowned(_owners, _required) daylimit(_daylimit) { } function kill(address _to) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external { suicide(_to); } function() { if (msg.value > 0) Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value); } function execute(address _to, uint _value, bytes _data) external onlyowner returns (bytes32 _r) { if (underLimit(_value)) { SingleTransact(msg.sender, _value, _to, _data); _to.call.value(_value)(_data); return 0; } _r = sha3(msg.data, block.number); if (!confirm(_r) && m_txs[_r].to == 0) { m_txs[_r].to = _to; m_txs[_r].value = _value; m_txs[_r].data = _data; ConfirmationNeeded(_r, msg.sender, _value, _to, _data); } } function confirm(bytes32 _h) onlymanyowners(_h) returns (bool) { if (m_txs[_h].to != 0) { m_txs[_h].to.call.value(m_txs[_h].value)(m_txs[_h].data); MultiTransact(msg.sender, _h, m_txs[_h].value, m_txs[_h].to, m_txs[_h].data); delete m_txs[_h]; return true; } } function clearPending() internal { uint length = m_pendingIndex.length; for (uint i = 0; i < length; ++i) delete m_txs[m_pendingIndex[i]]; super.clearPending(); } mapping (bytes32 => Transaction) m_txs; }'


var testCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(testSource);
var testContract = web3.eth.contract(testCompiled.multiowned.info.abiDefinition);

var test = testContract.new({
    from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
    data: testCompiled.multiowned.code, gas: 2000000}, 
    function(e, contract) {
      console.log(contract);
        admin.register(primaryAccount, contract.address, contenthash)

    admin.registerUrl(primaryAccount, hash, url)

})

var testContract = web3.eth.contract(testCompiled.multiowned.info.abiDefinition);
var myMultiply7 = testContract.at(primaryAccount);

var test = myMultiply7.multiowned.call();
```

First of all I don't know the call process is correct or please correct me
I need to call the functions in multisignature source code.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the contract has not been deployed.

Read the error message carefully:

```
TypeError: Cannot access member 'call' of undefined
```

The word 'undefined' suggests that attribute **multiowned** of **myMultiply7** has not been instantiated. Also, I cannot find the method **call()** in your code.

**Edit:**

Add the following code to your greeter deployment handling method:

```
function(e, contract){
    if(!e) {

      if(!contract.address) {
        console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");

      } else {
        console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
        console.log(contract);
      }

  }
```

to see when the contract is mined and added to the block chain. I still cannot see any method named **call()** in your contract code.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42505/discussion-on-answer-by-sebi-multisignature-contract-process-got-the-error-typee).

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are getting this error is that the callback function that you pass to `testContract.new()` is called **twice**, once when the transaction is sent, and again when the transaction is mined. You need to put anything that should happen after the contract is mined inside this, after a check to see whether the contract has been mined yet. This will look something like this:

```
//Multisignature source code for compiling

primaryAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
var testSource=' contract multiowned { struct PendingState { uint yetNeeded; uint ownersDone; uint index; } event Confirmation(address owner, bytes32 operation); event Revoke(address owner, bytes32 operation); event OwnerChanged(address oldOwner, address newOwner); event OwnerAdded(address newOwner); event OwnerRemoved(address oldOwner); event RequirementChanged(uint newRequirement); modifier onlyowner { if (isOwner(msg.sender)) _ } modifier onlymanyowners(bytes32 _operation) { if (confirmAndCheck(_operation)) _ } function multiowned(address[] _owners, uint _required) { m_numOwners = _owners.length + 1; m_owners[1] = uint(msg.sender); m_ownerIndex[uint(msg.sender)] = 1; for (uint i = 0; i < _owners.length; ++i) { m_owners[2 + i] = uint(_owners[i]); m_ownerIndex[uint(_owners[i])] = 2 + i; } m_required = _required; } function revoke(bytes32 _operation) external { uint ownerIndex = m_ownerIndex[uint(msg.sender)]; if (ownerIndex == 0) return; uint ownerIndexBit = 2**ownerIndex; var pending = m_pending[_operation]; if (pending.ownersDone & ownerIndexBit > 0) { pending.yetNeeded++; pending.ownersDone -= ownerIndexBit; Revoke(msg.sender, _operation); } } function changeOwner(address _from, address _to) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external { if (isOwner(_to)) return; uint ownerIndex = m_ownerIndex[uint(_from)]; if (ownerIndex == 0) return; clearPending(); m_owners[ownerIndex] = uint(_to); m_ownerIndex[uint(_from)] = 0; m_ownerIndex[uint(_to)] = ownerIndex; OwnerChanged(_from, _to); } function addOwner(address _owner) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external { if (isOwner(_owner)) return; clearPending(); if (m_numOwners >= c_maxOwners) reorganizeOwners(); if (m_numOwners >= c_maxOwners) return; m_numOwners++; m_owners[m_numOwners] = uint(_owner); m_ownerIndex[uint(_owner)] = m_numOwners; OwnerAdded(_owner); } function removeOwner(address _owner) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external { uint ownerIndex = m_ownerIndex[uint(_owner)]; if (ownerIndex == 0) return; if (m_required > m_numOwners - 1) return; m_owners[ownerIndex] = 0; m_ownerIndex[uint(_owner)] = 0; clearPending(); reorganizeOwners(); OwnerRemoved(_owner); } function changeRequirement(uint _newRequired) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external { if (_newRequired > m_numOwners) return; m_required = _newRequired; clearPending(); RequirementChanged(_newRequired); } function isOwner(address _addr) returns (bool) { return m_ownerIndex[uint(_addr)] > 0; } function hasConfirmed(bytes32 _operation, address _owner) constant returns (bool) { var pending = m_pending[_operation]; uint ownerIndex = m_ownerIndex[uint(_owner)]; if (ownerIndex == 0) return false; uint ownerIndexBit = 2**ownerIndex; if (pending.ownersDone & ownerIndexBit == 0) { return false; } else { return true; } } function confirmAndCheck(bytes32 _operation) internal returns (bool) { uint ownerIndex = m_ownerIndex[uint(msg.sender)]; if (ownerIndex == 0) return; var pending = m_pending[_operation]; if (pending.yetNeeded == 0) { pending.yetNeeded = m_required; pending.ownersDone = 0; pending.index = m_pendingIndex.length++; m_pendingIndex[pending.index] = _operation; } uint ownerIndexBit = 2**ownerIndex; if (pending.ownersDone & ownerIndexBit == 0) { Confirmation(msg.sender, _operation); if (pending.yetNeeded <= 1) { delete m_pendingIndex[m_pending[_operation].index]; delete m_pending[_operation]; return true; } else { pending.yetNeeded--; pending.ownersDone |= ownerIndexBit; } } } function reorganizeOwners() private returns (bool) { uint free = 1; while (free < m_numOwners) { while (free < m_numOwners && m_owners[free] != 0) free++; while (m_numOwners > 1 && m_owners[m_numOwners] == 0) m_numOwners--; if (free < m_numOwners && m_owners[m_numOwners] != 0 && m_owners[free] == 0) { m_owners[free] = m_owners[m_numOwners]; m_ownerIndex[m_owners[free]] = free; m_owners[m_numOwners] = 0; } } } function clearPending() internal { uint length = m_pendingIndex.length; for (uint i = 0; i < length; ++i) if (m_pendingIndex[i] != 0) delete m_pending[m_pendingIndex[i]]; delete m_pendingIndex; } uint public m_required; uint public m_numOwners; uint[256] m_owners; uint constant c_maxOwners = 250; mapping(uint => uint) m_ownerIndex; mapping(bytes32 => PendingState) m_pending; bytes32[] m_pendingIndex; } contract daylimit is multiowned { modifier limitedDaily(uint _value) { if (underLimit(_value)) _ } function daylimit(uint _limit) { m_dailyLimit = _limit; m_lastDay = today(); } function setDailyLimit(uint _newLimit) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external { m_dailyLimit = _newLimit; } function resetSpentToday() onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external { m_spentToday = 0; } function underLimit(uint _value) internal onlyowner returns (bool) { if (today() > m_lastDay) { m_spentToday = 0; m_lastDay = today(); } if (m_spentToday + _value >= m_spentToday && m_spentToday + _value <= m_dailyLimit) { m_spentToday += _value; return true; } return false; } function today() private constant returns (uint) { return now / 1 days; } uint public m_dailyLimit; uint public m_spentToday; uint public m_lastDay; } contract multisig { event Deposit(address from, uint value); event SingleTransact(address owner, uint value, address to, bytes data); event MultiTransact(address owner, bytes32 operation, uint value, address to, bytes data); event ConfirmationNeeded(bytes32 operation, address initiator, uint value, address to, bytes data); function changeOwner(address _from, address _to) external; function execute(address _to, uint _value, bytes _data) external returns (bytes32); function confirm(bytes32 _h) returns (bool); } contract Wallet is multisig, multiowned, daylimit { uint public version = 2; struct Transaction { address to; uint value; bytes data; } function Wallet(address[] _owners, uint _required, uint _daylimit) multiowned(_owners, _required) daylimit(_daylimit) { } function kill(address _to) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external { suicide(_to); } function() { if (msg.value > 0) Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value); } function execute(address _to, uint _value, bytes _data) external onlyowner returns (bytes32 _r) { if (underLimit(_value)) { SingleTransact(msg.sender, _value, _to, _data); _to.call.value(_value)(_data); return 0; } _r = sha3(msg.data, block.number); if (!confirm(_r) && m_txs[_r].to == 0) { m_txs[_r].to = _to; m_txs[_r].value = _value; m_txs[_r].data = _data; ConfirmationNeeded(_r, msg.sender, _value, _to, _data); } } function confirm(bytes32 _h) onlymanyowners(_h) returns (bool) { if (m_txs[_h].to != 0) { m_txs[_h].to.call.value(m_txs[_h].value)(m_txs[_h].data); MultiTransact(msg.sender, _h, m_txs[_h].value, m_txs[_h].to, m_txs[_h].data); delete m_txs[_h]; return true; } } function clearPending() internal { uint length = m_pendingIndex.length; for (uint i = 0; i < length; ++i) delete m_txs[m_pendingIndex[i]]; super.clearPending(); } mapping (bytes32 => Transaction) m_txs; }'


var testCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(testSource);
var testContract = web3.eth.contract(testCompiled.multiowned.info.abiDefinition);

var test;

var test = testContract.new({
    from:web3.eth.accounts[0], 
    data: testCompiled.multiowned.code, gas: 2000000}, 
    function(e, contract) {

      if(!e && contract.address){
          test = contract.test.call();
      }
});
```

`admin.register` doesn't actually do anything, since there's no official name registry yet.

`var myMultiply7 = testContract.at(primaryAccount);` is incorrect, that's essentially saying that there's a contract at your main address, which isn't true.

The nonce issue you're having is due to a bug in the develop version of geth, you should downgrad to the main branch to fix it

Comment: i try with your above changes but it give the Error: Transaction w/ invalid nonce. tx=0  state=1048617)